# What does "twice in seven years" mean regarding checking mezuzos?

Tags: halacha, time, mezuzah, inspection

We are told to check our mezuzos twice every seven years. What exactly does this mean? If the Chachamim/Poskim had meant once every 3.5 years, would they not have said this instead?

With regard to tashmish ha-mitah, I was told "twice a week" means that there should not be a seven-day period without two episodes. Does this mean the same thing, namely that there should not be a seven-year period without two checkings, which seems to boil down to approximately every six years?

Based on [how often do you have to check your mezuzot?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18311/how-often-do-you-have-to-check-your-mezuzot)

Comment: Presumably, it means any two times in a period of seven years.

Comment: @ba does it mean, then, that there should be no seven-year period without two checkings? Or is it a repeating seven-year cycle, where you might have seven years pass without a check?

Comment: How can seven years pass without two checkings if the halachah is that you have to check twice in seven years? They didn't say once in every 3.5 years, so it seems that you can check any two times in seven years. I don't see how seven years can pass without a check

Comment: @ba if it's viewed as a cycle, I can check in years 2, 4, 9, 13, and 5-11 have passed with only one check.

Comment: Oh, I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across a minhag to check one's mezzuzos every leap year in Adar Sheini. The reason for this custom is in order to ensure they are checked twice in seven years.

The Minhag is brought in אוצר טעמי המנהגים ח"ב עמ' שצו quoting בית ברוך ח"ב קונטרס המזוזה סי' רצא סע"ג.

Comment: This seems to be an answer to the other  question http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18311/how-often-do-you-have-to-check-your-mezuzot

Comment: @DoubleAA As I see it, it's an answer to this question. That question is asking how often, the answer is twice in seven years as per Y.D. 191. This question is asking what that actually means, my answer is that some have the minhag every leap year.

Comment: So what does twice every seven years actually mean?

Comment: @DoubleAA :-) Year [3, 6, 8, 11, 14, 17, and 19](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar#Leap_years) in the 19 year cycle.

Comment: That's more than 2 times per seven years though. Do you have a source that relates the two? And if you don't know what twice every seven years actually means, why did you answer a question asking just that?

Comment: @DoubleAA True. It's a way of making sure that the minimum of twice in seven years is kept. The source I quoted bring this as the reason.

Comment: I understand what your source said. The question asked for the minimum shiur and you said that some are careful to avoid getting close to it. How does that answer the question??

Comment: @DoubleAA I see your point. The question was how to apply the ruling in Shulchan Aruch to check mezzuzos twice in seven years practically, so I responded with a specific custom that is based on this psak. I agree this does not specifically adress the minimum amounts of checks required, perhaps it should have been a comment rather than an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Rav Moshe said every 3-1/2(ish) years.

Comment: Source........?

Comment: Do you mean R. Moshe Feinstein?