# What happens if your Mezzuzah comes off the wall

Tags: halacha, mistakes, mezuzah, intent-accident-purposely

I accidentally knocked my Mezzuzah off the wall , what is the process for putting it back on again ?

Comment: Same way you put it up the first time :) Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please consider registering your account, and don't forget to consult with your local Rabbi rather than relying on anything written here (we're just a bunch of anonymous people, right?). I look forward to seeing you around!

Comment: While it is off anyway, it should probably be checked. How about how long can I leave a mezuza missing.

Comment: @Epicentre Are you [asking another question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)?

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18311/1569

Comment: @Double AA No. I feel it's just an extension of the original that should be noted - i.e. should you just put it back up without checking.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the process is exactly the same as when you first [put it up](http://www.hasofer.com/page.pl?p=attach) and should be done promptly. The only discussion surrounds whether a new blessing is recited. Pitchei Teshuva (YD 289:1) compares the case to one whose Tallit fell off unexpectedly who needs to recite a new blessing upon redonning it (Shulchan Aruch OC 8:14). The Aruch HaShulchan (YD 289:4) rules this way as well, as does the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (11:7) and Mishneh Halachot (7:186). However, Rav Ovadiah Yosef (Yabia Omer OC 3:17:11) distinguishes the cases because by the Tallit, the obligation to wear Tzitzit vanishes as soon as one stops wearing the piece of clothing. On the other hand, the obligation to have a Mezuzah on the door remains in place even after the Mezuzah itself fell. Accordingly, he rules not to recite a new blessing. CYLOR for a final ruling.