# Kashrut of a scroll sealed in a mezuzah

Tags: mezuzah

Is it OK to seal a kosher scroll in a mezuzah, so it cannot be taken out?  If you did that, would the scroll remain kosher indefinitely?  If not, about how long would it last?

Comment: I'm not sure how anyone can know how long the mezuza would last. Probably depends on the circumstances and environment.

Comment: Aren't basically all mezuzot sealed in cases? To take them out you usually break the seal (tape, glue, nails, screws, etc.). Are you discussing a seal that physically can't be broken? What is that?

Comment: @DoubleAA -- Some are not sealed.  You lift a metal strip anchored at one end and slip the scroll in.  That makes it easier to check for kashrut periodically.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18311/how-often-do-you-have-to-check-your-mezuzot/25671#25671